# Google map places API getPlace() only return name attribute for some addresses

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an address search box using the google map autocomplete library:

```
var autocompleter = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(item);
```

There is an odd occasion that an address only returns a name attribute:

```
Object {name: "138 Manukau Road, Pukekohe, New Zealand"}
```

But other addresses are giving more data, such as:

```
Object {address_components: Array[7], adr_address: "<span class="street-address">430 Queen St</span>, …n>, <span class="country-name">New Zealand</span>", formatted_address: "430 Queen St, Auckland, Auckland 1010, New Zealand", geometry: Object, icon: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png"…}address_components: Array[7]adr_address: "<span class="street-address">430 Queen St</span>, <span class="extended-address">Auckland</span>, <span class="locality">Auckland</span> <span class="postal-code">1010</span>, <span class="country-name">New Zealand</span>"formatted_address: "430 Queen St, Auckland, Auckland 1010, New Zealand"geometry: Objecthtml_attributions: Array[0]icon: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png"id: "00fce9b1c43ac960068949cbf32eecb587b0b020"name: "430 Queen St"place_id: "ChIJQfHW8OVHDW0RyHgQRLy8fKc"reference: "CqQBlgAAAIDnkWNQ4cmU624FV6l_bAxmI27czZoytmzrrEWVaXgR5LcZuFqt1cL3WIMzoWhmZNhftRzhLUVwpFjqmw3qwKIqugj02HrvU5x6PtUvepPNPV-08pin_PvRU-__mMMH3N2vILIOLM_AnYFMqNG5MArF4ChZXJxZj6vk7PI3ORJe1W6QjIXoPgesL379E4WUCjrZ0fjv3KgqzB-G4f-8A5MSEN5S47-QZqkY5sl37cIQFWQaFLg4InSVLpYGg8n1gGO958TcA4UK"scope: "GOOGLE"types: Array[1]url: "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=430+Queen+St,+Auckland,+Auckland+1010,+New+Zealand&ftid=0x6d0d47e5f0d6f141:0xa77cbcbc441078c8"vicinity: "Auckland"__proto__: Object
```

I have found a [similar issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4727) which raised by someone in 2012, and looks like it has not been attended.

Comment: The code works on 99% of locations. However, it consistently doesn't work on a certain subset of destinations. Silver Peak is one, El Paso TX is another. If I do console.log on the google place object, here are the results:
Object {name: "Silver Peak, NV, United States"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly the very same address now returning correct data, google must be watching these errors and fix them as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

This problem was happening intermittently for me and usually out of the blue.

Turns out that if you get a result from Autocomplete with only a name property, you can use the google.maps.places.AutocompleteService to finish the job.

For example, call this if you only get a name back (sending the input element in el)

```
        function getPlace(result, el, callback) {
            var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
            if (result.name.length > 0) {
                var d = { input: result.name, offset: result.name.length };
                autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(d, function (list, status) {
                    if (list == null || list.length == 0) callback(null);

                    var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(el);
                    var ref = { 'reference': list[0].reference }

                    placesService.getDetails(ref, function (detailsResult, placesServiceStatus) {
                        if (placesServiceStatus == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            callback(detailsResult);
                        }
                        else {
                            callback(null);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
```

This helped me a lot
http://plnkr.co/edit/GF3nM3XfYX9El2w11pGo?p=preview

Comment: Fwiw, this works fine in stock JS, but it's a bit problematic in Typescript. The docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) show that PlacesService.getDetails should expect a PlaceDetailsRequest, but that interface doesn't have "reference" on it. Not sure how to make TS happy about that.

Comment: Ok, for Typescript you can get around the fact that `reference` as an option to `getDetails()` is undocumented. It's not great, but it looks like `const ref = <any>{ 'reference': list[0].reference }`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the google service is not able to geocode your address and only return to you the name of the address found. The reason could be that the service has no aditional data to give you for those adress. 
You can just not show those incomplete address to the user or try to geocode that address by another service like `OSM Geocoder`
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Comment: Google sometimes returns data for these addresses, so I know it is available. These place ids come from a Google Autocomplete result, how would I be able to filter them out to the user?

Comment: You can do this by modifying the source code if its posible or you can just bind your own geocoder reqiesting data to several geocoder services. Or you can also create your own geocoder service with you purposes using postgreSQL/postGIS for example. Maybe you arrive to máximum request allowed and dont send you the entire data.

Answer (score 1):

From [Google Maps Autocomplete Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete):

> Returns the details of the Place selected by user if the details were
>   successfully retrieved. **Otherwise returns a stub Place object, with
>   the name property set to the current value of the input field**.

So the answer is that the getPlace method is just failing for specific places. Not sure how to solve this, but gets us one step closer to the answer.

EDIT: FIXED IT!

For my app, I'm loading multiple libraries for google maps (geometry and places). Switching the order that the libraries were loaded fixed the issue, and I don't know why.

Change:

```
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=[KEY]&libraries=geometry,places
```

to

```
maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=[KEY]&libraries=places,geometry
```